# Why does inotifywait create files with "swp" or goutputstream in their names?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, inotify

I'm trying to learn about *inotifywait*. I installed *inotify-tools*:

```
Start-Date: 2019-08-31  18:11:48
Commandline: apt install inotify-tools
Requested-By: dkb (1000)
Install: inotify-tools:amd64 (3.14-7), libinotifytools0:amd64 (3.14-7, automatic)
End-Date: 2019-08-31  18:11:58
```

I made this script, *jl.sh*, to copy any modified file in *~/Desktop/vvtemp* over to *~/Public* and to timestamp the copied file:

```
#!/bin/bash
dir_to_watch="/home/dkb/Desktop/vvtemp/"

inotifywait -m -e modify --format '%w%f' "${dir_to_watch}" | while read line
do
s=$line
     newname=/home/dkb/Public/$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)"-${s##*/}"
     cp $line $newname
done
```

- I created a file called *test.txt* and started the script in one terminal. There were no errors or warnings.
- In another terminal, I opened *test.txt* with *nano*, edited it, saved it and closed it just the one time.
- Then I edited the same file using *gedit* and *geany*

I looked at the listing of files in the target folder, *~/Public*:

```
dkb@Udin:~/Public$ ll
total 36
drwxr-xr-x  2 dkb dkb 4096 Aug 31 18:27 ./
drwxr-xr-x 17 dkb dkb 4096 Aug 31 18:08 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 dkb dkb 1024 Aug 31 18:24 20190831182416-.test.txt.swp
-rw-r--r--  1 dkb dkb 1024 Aug 31 18:24 20190831182419-.test.txt.swp
-rw-r--r--  1 dkb dkb  159 Aug 31 18:24 20190831182441-test.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 dkb dkb  179 Aug 31 18:26 20190831182619-.goutputstream-QN1A7Z
-rw-r--r--  1 dkb dkb  198 Aug 31 18:26 20190831182638-.goutputstream-UDEB7Z
-rw-r--r--  1 dkb dkb  210 Aug 31 18:27 20190831182722-.goutputstream-0X2K7Z
-rw-r--r--  1 dkb dkb  221 Aug 31 18:27 20190831182733-.goutputstream-01D86Z
dkb@Udin:~/Public$
```

- The first three files are related to editing and saving *test.txt* with *nano*. The first two files have a *.swp* suffix. The third file is the intended file with the intended timestamped filename.
- Then I tried editing the same file with *gedit* or *geany*. These editors created the backup files, one for each time I modified and saved the file, but the resulting backups, although they had the intended content, had filenames like *20190831182733-.goutputstream-01D86Z*. So it seems that the timestamp is honored but the "basename" isn't.

My questions are:

- why are two *.swp* files created by *inotifywait* when I use *nano*?
- why isn't the intended name generated when I use *gedit* or *geany*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment "set locking" in /etc/nanorc or ~/.nanorc or $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nano/nanorc or ~/.config/nano/nanorc

```
## Enable vim-style lock-files.  This is just to let a vim user know you
## are editing a file [s]he is trying to edit and vice versa.  There are
## no plans to implement vim-style undo state in these files.
#set locking
```

If you debug inotify you can see that gedit does not modify test:

```
OPEN test
CREATE .goutputstream-F4776Z
OPEN .goutputstream-F4776Z
ATTRIB .goutputstream-F4776Z
CLOSE_WRITE:CLOSE test
MODIFY .goutputstream-F4776Z
MOVED_FROM .goutputstream-F4776Z
MOVED_TO test
CLOSE_WRITE:CLOSE test
OPEN test
ACCESS test
CLOSE_NOWRITE:CLOSE test
```

but both uses event "close_write" or you can follow the inotify events and recreate the steps on your backup location.

Comment: Thanks! I went with `close_write` and modified /etc/nanorc as you indicated.